# Load data infile import not working and none of the other topics helped

Tags: mysql, csv, data-import

This is the table I want to import in:

```sql
create table if not exists Medici(
        m_id int unsigned AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        m_nume VARCHAR(50),
        m_prenume VARCHAR(50),
        Statut ENUM('primar', 'specialist'),
        Specialitate VARCHAR(50)
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;
```

And the CSV starts with:

```
Nume,Prenume,Tip,Specialitate
Bunica,Mihai-Daniel,primar,reumatologie
Donca,Cornelia-Ana,primar,chirurgie
Achiriloaie,Lorand-Levente,specialist,neurologie
```

The code I wrote is:

```sql
load data infile 'D:/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx/medici.txt'
    into table Medici
    character set utf8
    fields terminated by ','
    lines starting by 'Nume,Prenume,Tip,Specialitate\n'
          terminated by '\n' 
    (m_nume,m_prenume,Statut,Specialitate);
```

Note: I changed terminated with `\n`, `\r`, `\r\n`, and I still get 1 row. Even with removing lines terminated by and it's not working.

Note: I pasted quickly and messed up a bit, there are 4 rows there. And ye the CSV I assume it's formated correctly

more of the code here:

```
Nume,Prenume,Tip,Specialitate
Bunica,Mihai-Daniel,primar,reumatologie
Donca,Cornelia-Ana,primar,chirurgie
Achiriloaie,Lorand-Levente,specialist,neurologie
Papuc,Raducu-Liviu,primar,homeopatie
Cucuiu,Nutu,primar,ortopedie
Buia,Tache,specialist,ginecologie
Dragomanu,Mitrut,specialist,ecografie
Ticu,Simona,specialist,psihiatrie
Ene,Adrian-Stefan,specialist,pediatrie
Copae,Toma,primar,neurologie
Hotoi,Dragos Alin,specialist,pediatrie
Ceafalau,Vincenţiu Mihail,primar,pediatrie
Briceag,Anca Stefana,primar,imagistica
Condrea,Nutu,primar,fizioterapie
Cruceru,Ioana-Loredana,primar,dermatologie
Soarece,Dan-Cristian,primar,o.r.l.
Tatasel,Alexandru-Ovidiu,specialist,psihologie
Sterian,Gologaneanu,primar,chirurgie
Postelnicu,Habib,primar,chirurgie
Silviu ,Adrian Ionut,primar,dermatologie
Paius,Ioana,specialist,ortopedie
Borza,Marius Florian,specialist,fizioterapie
Tamas,Ciprian Costel,primar,chirurgie
Ograzeanu,Cristina Alexandra,primar,endocrinologie
Rildo,Alex,specialist,ecografie
```

In the CSV, these lines are merged ( one row to another )
For example:
After `reumatologie` it starts with the name but when I paste the code you can see it's actually an `\n Bunica,Mihai-Daniel,primar,reumatologieDonca,`(.... here is 2nd row and so on)

Comment: Are you sure the CSV is formatted correctly? From the data it looks like there are 4 rows in the CSV (header then 3 rows of data).

Comment: thanks for posting mate, but I wrote more code there and i explained it a bit at the end how the data stays in that csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command:

> **load data local infile**
>
> 'D:/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxx/medici.txt'
>
> **into table** Medici  character set utf8 **fields terminated by** ','
>
> **lines terminated by** '\n' **IGNORE 1 LINES**  (m_nume,m_prenume,Statut,Specialitate);

Comment: Thanks for comment rizzz86, but if you look at the code I wrote it's exactly the same. And i mentioned as well that i tried writing \n, \r, \r\n :) so it didnt help at all

Comment: yep and i get 1 row, not all of them

Comment: Oh I missed one of your point ... Please see the updated command now ... I hope that will work now

Comment: altough i'm wondering how do you symbolize the no space (Ex: word1word2) between 2 rows at the 'lines terminated by'  ?maybe it works like that

Comment: To try your improved command i had to remove the column names that are in the beginning of the csv ( named it to medicitest2). Removed the character set utf8 and lines starting by and i get 108 rows out of 108 . It's something but can't figure out what i'm doing wrong

Comment: I've edited my post and the conclusion: Is that if i try to remove the text of the columns in the beginning of the csv (Nume,Prenume,Tip,Specialitate) and actually leave out there only the name of the medics i have to import into medici. It works. But need it to work with lines starting by aswell so i can include the whole text: including Nume,Prenume,Tip,Specialitate

Comment: No dont remove the column in the beginning. Try the updated command it will skip the headers. Also add the utf part. See the updated command

Comment: That's great ... Please accept the answer if it has worked :)

Comment: Yeah sure, but where do you accept the answer. I'm quite new around here and never posted here :). I think I found where, just let me know if it worked to accept it

Comment: You have already accepted my answer by clicking on the tick mark ... now it is green that means the answer has been accepted. You can also up-vote/down-vote the questions/answers by clicking on the up and down arrows that are with the answer and question